# historical quotes for convertible debentures of a defunct company

Tags: stocks, stock-valuation

How do I locate quotes for International Consumer Brands 12.0% convertible debentures (default date June 14, 1997) for the time period from the date of issuance of such debentures through June 14, 1997?  The Cusip no. was 459356AB7?

Comment: Given that International Consumer Brands was delisted by Nasdaq in 1991 for having an insufficient amount of capital to retain its listing, it's unlikely that the those convertible instruments were ever listed on any sort of exchange and OTC pricing from that period is practically impossible to find too.

Comment: However, I do have a clue for you to follow... Home Safety Only! Inc is referenced against ICBI, so it's possible that company took over the shell of ICBI.  I have no further details on that company.  A google search revealed it's an inactive Miami, FL corporation.